# Why are most islands in the Caspian Sea elongated and some of them even have tails?

Tags: geology, islands

I was seeing the Caspian Sea from Google Maps satellite mode and I found most islands are elongated in shape (the biggest of them Ogurja ada or Ogurchinsky island).

Also there are islands that have tails, like Khara Zira island and the one to the northwest of it.

What's the geological reason for the existence of these islands?

My hypothesis for the existence of these islands is that they aren't just underwater peaks. But short underwater mountain ranges.

Comment: look up sandbar, barrier island, and sand spit formation.